# Rotate an object around it's local z-axis until it's local x axis falls into a specific plane

Tags: 3d, rotation

I'm working in 3D space (Blender, Python).

I have an object with an arbitrary rotation. I need to rotate it, so the local x axis is normal to a given axis (imagine a plane, the x axis can be anything as long as it's a directional vector of that plane). Now I need to rotate the object **only** around it's local z axis (freezing the 2 others) until the local x axis aligns with the plane.

Right now I approximate and then use a while loop, rotating a small amount around the local z until it fits, but I'm sure there is a mathematical solution. The solution does not need to be python, a mathematical description should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the object's rotation (3x3 matrix) to be `R`, and the plane's (unit) normal in world-frame to be `n'`. To calculate the transformed normal in the object's local frame, `n`, apply the inverse of `R` (= transpose) to `n'`. It is more convenient to work in the local frame:

[image: ![enter image description here]

`w` is the "desired" X-axis. It is either *parallel* or *anti-parallel* to `n ^ z`, where `^` is the *cross-product*. Since there are two solutions (`w` and `-w`), we will choose the positive one in this instance.

Before we do anything else though, we need to check if `n` is co-linear with `z`. If it is then the `x` axis will already be in the plane (besides, there would be infinitely many solutions for `w`), and we can return straight away. We do so by computing the *dot product* of `n` and `z`. If this is close to 1 or -1 (within some `EPSILON` depending on your floating point format), then they are co-linear.

Once we have `w`, we can reduce the problem to 2D:

[image]

To obtain the angle `θ` (to rotate around the local Z-axis by), *normalize* `w`, and take the inverse cosine of the dot-product of `w` and `x`.

However, we also need to know which direction to rotate in (clockwise or anti-clockwise when viewing in the opposite direction to Z). However this is simple - if `w.Y > 0` then rotate anti-clockwise, else clockwise (change the sign of `θ`).

Finally we can calculate the rotation matrix to be applied,

[image]

**Post-multiply** this with the original rotation matrix: `R_new = R * S`, and we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed and correct answer, problem solved